# Is it possible to specify a machine type (e.g small/micro) when deploying to Managed VM?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm migrating some simple web apps (Node based static pages with some questionnaires and a very small amount of back end processing) to App Engine.  I have them working well. Impressed with how easy it was!

However, I have a couple of questions that baffle me.

1) Why does GCE always deploy 2 machines?  Is there a way of specifying to only run 1?  I really don't need loads of redundancy, and our traffic is expected to be light.

2) I have tried to specify the machine type in app.yaml to be 'micro'. Call me cheap, but we really don't need much capacity.  I have tried various perameters e.g.

```
resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: .2
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

but it always seems to deploy 'small' machines.  Is there a log somewhere that would tell me that the commmand was valid, but it chose to ingore it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha! Sorry, with a bit more googling around I found an answer to Q2

[Setting f1-micro resource limits in app.yaml for google cloud compute node.js app without vm_settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273834/setting-f1-micro-resource-limits-in-app-yaml-for-google-cloud-compute-node-js-ap)

> As Jeff and Greg both replied, "Google adds a little overhead on the
>   VM before picking a machine type. This is around 400mb of ram. So they
>   told me if you want an f1-micro try requesting .2 or lower as Greg
>   mentioned."
>
> I had to drop to .18 to get it to deploy as f1-micro, but the general
>   idea that google is adding overhead is solid.

Dropping down the memory_gb to 0.18 did the trick.

Simply adding

```
resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: .18
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

and deploying with the command

```
gcloud preview app deploy --stop-previous-version --force --promote
```

to make damn sure it was made #1 seemed to work - no loss in performance so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify machine type, not just required resources. By adding into `app.yaml`:

```
beta_settings:
  machine_type: f1-micro
```

Also, if you want to always use 1 instance add this:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Comment: Can i use beta_settings with automatic scaling or not ??

Comment: description: beta_setting key can not be used with env:flex
    field: machine_type